# angular morphing current view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say i have two custom elements `<card1>` and `<card2>` that are independent of each other meaning that i can create an arbitrary amount of each and each of them have different models.

What i want is when an action happens in `<card1>` it creates a `<card2>` within `<card1>` (preferably with some animation) or morphs `<card1>` into a `<card2>`. I dont really want to have to predefine a `<card2>` within `<card1>` and hide until the interaction happens. because i want it to be scalable if i decide to create a card3 or card4 and have them appear based on the interaction

what would be the best way to structure the view, controller, template, ...?

Comment: Fairly easy by pushing data into arrays .. what have you tried?

Comment: can you elaborate on that? my struggle is with how to create the view not necessarily attaching the right data to it